# jQuery slideshow blocks animation with opacity

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a plugin for jQuery that will create this effect?

http://zipbolt.com.au/

I want an image fade in and transition with blocks of varying opacity.

I could possibly modify nivoslider.com as it does a similar effect but only does bars, horizontally or vertically on an image.

Comment: http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/

Comment: Thanks, this should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it costs money (just a few bucks, it is worth it): http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-banner-rotator-slideshow/109046

Live demo: http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-banner-rotator-slideshow/full_screen_preview/109046

Comment: Im interested to know how easy it would be to modify it to create a more specific effect than one on the demos. I guess I would have to buy it to work that out.